# Postgres aggregate alias for group_concat using string_agg

Tags: postgresql, group-concat

I know that postgres does not have group_concat, but I want to emulate it for strings by using string_agg (or any other way that works).

I need to have the function called group_concat because of an inability to change legacy code.

How can I do this?

For what its worth, I also tried implementing `group_concat` using regular concat, and ran into an error there as well:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE group_concat (text) (sfunc = concat, stype=text)
```

error:

> "function concat(text,text) does not exist"

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html.  However, I would recommend that you change the application rather than the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See update. Its not possible for policy reasons, though trust me, I would prefer that

Comment: @soandos: I don't think you have a choice. You might get away with simulating `group_concat()` but the MySQL syntax deviates in so many areas from standard SQL and the one used by Postgres that you won't get far with keeping the existing SQL statements as they are. The first things that come to mind are date or interval literals, the strange (not to say broken) "boolean" handling in MySQL or implicit type casts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I only need to define this for strings. I don't care about any other types

Comment: I am not talking about `group_concat()` for other types. I am talking about the huge differences in syntax between Postgres and MySQL. I can't imagine that you will succeed in keeping SQL statements written for MySQL without any changes in your code when you run that against Postgres. It simply won't work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The database is currently H2, which has a postgres emulation mode (don't ask why)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-- drop aggregate if exists group_concat(text);
CREATE AGGREGATE group_concat(text) (
  SFUNC=textcat,
  STYPE=text
);

select group_concat(x) from unnest('{a,b,c,d}'::text[]) as x;
```

`textcat` is the function used internally by the `||` operator:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ||(
  PROCEDURE = textcat,
  LEFTARG = text,
  RIGHTARG = text);
```

---

**Update**

To make the comma as the separator:

```
--drop aggregate if exists group_concat(text);
--drop function if exists group_concat_trans(text, text);

create or replace function group_concat_trans(text, text)
  returns text
  language sql
  stable as 
$$select concat($1,case when $1 is not null and $2 is not null then ',' end,$2)$$;

create aggregate group_concat(text) (
  sfunc=group_concat_trans,
  stype=text);

select group_concat(x) from unnest(array['a','b','c',null,'d']) as x;
```

```
╔══════════════╗
║ group_concat ║
╠══════════════╣
║ a,b,c,d      ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the comma in between the values. Is there a way to make that passed in?

Comment: @soandos . . . You could have the function default to using a comma, but you can't implement the `separator` syntax in Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can I have it default to comma then?

Comment: @soandos You did not mention about comma. In this case you should to define yet another function. Answer updated.

Comment: @soandos PS Define the function as `stable` to make it faster.

Comment: Is it also pure, or not really?

Comment: @soandos Don't understand the question.

Comment: +1, I think this is as good as you're going to get it via DDL statements. Unfortunately, performance starts to collapse after a few thousand records, as each concat needs to copy the intermediate result into a brand new `text` value. `string_agg()` avoids this by using internal accumulators, but I don't think you can emulate this unless you're willing to write some server-side C code...

Comment: How to do it when the values are numeric and not text?

Comment: @Jus12 `cast(value as text)`?